# Wireless headset with instant response that works in the wind

Tags: bluetooth, headset

I'm looking for a bluetooth headset which meets the following requirements:

- primary use to talk on the phone, so audio quality must be good
- wind cancelling, so if I'm riding a bike and talking on the phone, the other person will be able to understand what I'm saying
- secondary use to interact with my phone (e.g. something like Google Assistant).

For point #2 I currently have a wind cancelling headset (up to 19mph), but audio quality isn't that great - sometimes I have people tell me they can't hear me even when I'm in a quiet room and switching to the phone mic immediately resolves the issue.

Point #3 is also important with regards to being able to instantly interact with my phone.  My current headset I have to tap a button, give a voice command which causes it to connect to the phone (assuming it doesn't think I said "cancel" which happens about half the time) and then there is about a 10 second wait until it connects. By this time whatever thought I wanted to record I am likely to have forgotten or the number of times it said "cancel" instead of connecting has made me abandon the attempt completely.

Google Pixel Buds seem to have point #3, it appears they respond instantly and direct your audio to Google Assistant. However, I have read mixed responses to whether they work in the wind and am thinking they may have issues on a bike at 20mph - although whether this is with *hearing* the other person or them hearing me is uncertain.